# How Can I perform Distributed search inside solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I am doing a distributed search inside Solr on 4 diffrent solr servers on different machine. I have extended my class to Query and I would like to perform distributed search. I have created a solr query using solrj. But when I make a query to solr sometimes it gives me a correct result and sometimes incorrect. It gives me incorrect result only when some shards throws query parsing exception. So my question is can I perform a distributed search inside solr. Outline of my class from where I am making a distributed solr search is as given below.

```
public class CutomClass extends Query {
    // some other code....
    public Weight createWeight(IndexSearcher searcher1) throws IOException {
         SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
         query.setQuery("*:*");
         query.add(ShardParams.SHARDS, getShards);
         query.setStart(0);
         query.setRows(0);
         query.set("sort", "score desc");       
         query.setFacet(true);
         query.addFacetField("CLIENT");
         query.setFacetMinCount(1);
         QueryResponse queryResponse = solrServer.query(query, SolrRequest.METHOD.POST);
    }
    // some other code....
}
```

Sometimes it gives follwing parsing exception on some shard and the result comes incorrect.

org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse '*:*': Encountered "" at line 1, column 0.

Comment: What query do you send it when you get that error? If your query contains ":" it needs to be escaped, since : is field:text delimiter. EDIT: Nvm, I just saw your edit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can perform a distributed search in Solr. If you are using a single collection (say collection1) and using the following Solr URL to create the solrServer object, then you are doing a distributed search by default.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?
```

This URL let you query across all the shards in **collection1**, whether they are in same or different machine. But, if you have separate collections and you want a search among those collections, please follow http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud.

To know more about distributed search, please look into https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch.

You can simply comment the following line.

```
query.add(ShardParams.SHARDS, getShards);
```

And yes, `*:*` is not the problematic part in your program as stated by D. Kasipovic. Query can contain `:`. You need to provide query like `field:text`. Problem occurs when the **text** part is having "**:**". Then you need to escape `:` by `\:`.

Please modify the URL to do a distributed search and then let us know what happens.